# Absolutely integrable function with infinite number of singularities

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, singularity

> Question: Suppose $(a_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of numbers in [0,1]. Find an absolutely integrable function $f$ on $[0,1]$ with singularities $(a_i)$.
>   Here the integral is in the sense of Riemann integral.

I found a possible answer but I do not know how to examine it when the sequence $(a_i)$ is given in an arbitrary way, or in the special case where $(a_i)$ exhausts all the rationals in $[0,1]$. Can somebody give me a hint on the examination of this function or give me another example if it doesn't work?

My answer: define f(x) to be $$ f(x) = \frac{1}{\limsup_{n \to \infty}\left(\sqrt[2n]{\prod_{i=1}^n|x-a_i|}\right)}$$ if $ x\neq a_i$ and 0 if $ x=a_i$.

Comment: how does "absolutely integrable" fit into this? Also does "singularities" mean "discontinuities"?

Comment: @zhw.: Here "absolutely integrable” means that |f| is Riemann integrable and "singularities" means "discontinuities". I find this problem is not well posed because the set of discontinuities is closed and if we require that Q∩[0,1] is exactly the set of discontinuities of f, then there is no such f.

Comment: Why not just say find a nonnegative Riemann integrable function on $[0,1]$ that is discontinuous at each $a_i?$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Define $g(x) = 0, x<0,$ $g(x) = 1, x\ge 1.$ Consider the function

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{g(x-a_n)}{2^n}.$$

Comment: I don't see how you define g on [0,1), but I don't think it will work. Suppose f is discontinuous on Q∩[0,1], then f would have to be discontinuous on [0,1], which means f is not Riemann integrable on [0,1].

Comment: I changed my answer; I had forgotten the sequence $(a_n)$ was given. No matter what the  $a_n$'s are, $f$ will be discontinuous at each $a_n,$ and continuous everywhere else. Hence this $f$ is always Riemann integrable.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't make it clear. A point x is a singularity if in every neighborhood of x, f is unbounded.

Comment: An unbounded function on [0,1] is not Riemann integrable there.

Comment: Here Riemann integral is in the extended sense, as an improper integral.

Comment: Usually an improper Riemann integral is a limit of Riemann integrals, but if the a_n's are the rationals, that won't be possible. Earlier you wrote "Here "absolutely integrable” means that |f| is Riemann integrable and "singularities" means "discontinuities". So it looks like that is false. It would have been nice to have all of these definitions made clear at the beginning. They still aren't clear.